# connecting to server http Client

Tags: java, android, json, apache, httpclient

```
try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://nayyar.5gbfree.com/welcome.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

                Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
```

I am trying to connect to server for the very first time. i copied the code from internet trying to execute. but always showing error on nameValuePairs. i don't know what is this. and why the error is. anybody explain me the code and the error or explain me to connect to server in his/her own way via code. Shall be very thankful.

Comment: No, we won't _give you code_. When posting problems with code you've written, **always** state your goals. If there are errors, **always** post the stack trace or compiler error. Or explain how it behaves in regards to your expectations.

Comment: that means , you should declare those nameValuePairs !

Comment: error : nameValuePairs cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Have you tried looking up that error? You're honestly showing no effort at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a NameValuePair list... like this

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://nayyar.5gbfree.com/welcome.php");
List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                    postParameters);
httppost.setEntity(formEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

and then get the data in this way

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httppost.getEntity().getContent()));

br.readLine(); // Save it in a String variable or whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

What data must receive your POST? for example if the url needs "id" and "user":

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://nayyar.5gbfree.com/welcome.php");

            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "Jorgesys!"));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    ...
    ...
    ...
```